# How do I create and apply a configuration schema for an existing custom module?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a custom module, already running for a longer while, but I did not take into account that the configuration would have to support translation. I have had no config/schema/module_name.schema.yml file at the time of installation.

I created the schema file, looked into implementing `hook_update()`. I was just about to start implementing it, but I checked the output of `\Drupal::service('config.typed')->getDefinition(DrupalHooks::CONFIG_KEY);` just in case. The schema file was automagically absorbed by either `drush cr`, or loaded by the code snippet itself.

I don't find my module listed on the admin/config/regional/config-translation page. Also, the other modules shown in that list seem to always have a *Translate* tab on their configuration page. My module doesn't get that either.

What am I supposed to do to make it translatable? Is there any hook I should implement, or am I missing something else?

Comment: This is my experience too, a new schema file is discovered by clearing the cache. Are you sure this is really the issue? What happens if you re-install the module or install it on a fresh site, is it working then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the "Translate" tab listed on your module's configuration page you additionally need to provide a `module_name.config_translation.yml` in your module's root.

```
module_name.settings:
  title: 'Module Name'
  base_route_name: module_name.admin_settings
  names:
    - module_name.settings
```

Look for existing `module_name.config_translation.yml` file in core and contrib and you'll get the pattern no problem.

Comment: Yes, that was it, great. I also found it described in more detail here: https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2018/05/01/drupal-8-how-to-translate-the-config-api